# Adding traces to plotly chart based on the data in plotly r

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make a plotly chart for a shiny app. As of now I am doing is hardcoding by adding each trace. But I did realize that the columns in data get updated and the way I am doing that will not plot the data. How can I make sure tht whenever the data is added with a column name which has `sale` in it it would get added to the plot. Below are the data and the way I am doing it currently.

```
d1 <- tibble::tribble(
      ~Date, ~apple_count, ~apple_sale, ~banana_count, ~banana_sale, ~orange_count, ~orange_sale, ~peaches_count, ~peaches_sale, ~watermelon_count, ~watermelon_sale, ~strawberry_count, ~strawberry_sale,
  "8/19/19",  10882.05495,      239575,             0,            0,             0,            0,              0,             0,       9643.600102,           630827,                 0,                0,
  "8/20/19",    516.29755,       11281,             0,            0,             0,            0,              0,             0,       6041.538067,           510219,           1694.44,           684210,
  "8/21/19",     949.4084,       20150,             0,            0,             0,            0,              0,             0,       5371.758106,           565440,           9105.89,          3695182,
  "8/22/19",    3950.5318,       88679,             0,            0,             0,            0,              0,             0,       5238.308826,           576678,           6179.47,          2501560,
  "8/23/19",   2034.02055,       45672,             0,            0,             0,            0,              0,             0,        4994.43054,           518081,           7366.31,          2984563,
  "8/24/19",   1770.50415,       38553,             0,            0,             0,            0,              0,             0,       5001.303585,           551733,           6275.43,          2531400,
)
```

Below is the code.

```
output$saleplot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(x = ~d1$Date, y = ~d1$apple_sale, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', name = 'apple', fill = 'tozeroy',fillcolor = 'rgba( 71,238,171, 0.5)') %>%
    add_trace(x = ~d1$Date, y = ~d1$banana_sale, name = 'banana',fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'rgba(255,0,127,0.5)') %>%
    add_trace(x = ~d1$Date, y = ~d1$orange_sale, name = 'orange',fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'rgba(255,255,51, 0.5)') %>%
    add_trace(x = ~d1$Date, y = ~d1$peach_sale, name = 'peach',fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'rgba(127,0,255,0.5)') %>%
    add_trace(x = ~d1$Date, y = ~d1$watermelon_sale, name = 'watermelon',fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)')%>%
    add_trace(x = ~d1$Date, y = ~d1$strawberry_sale, name = 'strawberry',fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'rgba(0,102,204, 0.5)') %>%
    layout(title = 'sale By Day',
           #  xaxis = list(title = 'Date',rangeslider = list(type = "date")),
           xaxis = list(title = 'Date'),
           yaxis = list(title = 'sale'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

## Initialization

Get columns that contain "sale" and provide colors for plotting.

In shiny app context, you can use detect whether `sale_columns` changes, if TRUE, update the graph.

```r
sale_columns <- stringr::str_subset(colnames(d1),stringr::regex("sale",ignore_case = TRUE))
# you can provide your own color scheme.
fill_colors <- apply(grDevices::col2rgb(grDevices::rainbow(12)),2,function(x){
    sprintf("rgba(%s,%s,%s,0.5,)",x[1],x[2],x[3])
})
```

```r
> sale_columns
[1] "apple_sale"      "banana_sale"     "orange_sale"     "peaches_sale"    "watermelon_sale" "strawberry_sale"
> fill_colors
 [1] "rgba(255,0,0,0.5,)"   "rgba(255,128,0,0.5,)" "rgba(255,255,0,0.5,)" "rgba(128,255,0,0.5,)" "rgba(0,255,0,0.5,)"  
 [6] "rgba(0,255,128,0.5,)" "rgba(0,255,255,0.5,)" "rgba(0,128,255,0.5,)" "rgba(0,0,255,0.5,)"   "rgba(128,0,255,0.5,)"
[11] "rgba(255,0,255,0.5,)" "rgba(255,0,128,0.5,)"
```

## Using For Loop to Update

```r
plotly_plot <- plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'none')
# add one trace for each "sale" column
for(i in 1:length(sale_columns)){
    plotly_plot <- plotly_plot %>%
        add_trace(x = d1$Date, y = d1[[sale_columns[i]]], name = sale_columns[i],fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = fill_colors[i])
}

plotly_plot %>%
    layout(title = 'sale By Day',
           #  xaxis = list(title = 'Date',rangeslider = list(type = "date")),
           xaxis = list(title = 'Date'),
           yaxis = list(title = 'sale'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

Would select variables that include 'sale' and separate into another column. Would convert data from wide to long for plotting. You can also create a vector of colors to sample from for plotting (one option).

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Convert data from wide to long
d2 <- d1 %>%
  select(Date, ends_with("sale")) %>%
  pivot_longer(ends_with("sale")) %>%
  separate(name, into = "fruit", sep = "_", remove = TRUE, extra = "drop")

# Vector of assigned colors
qual_col_pals <- brewer.pal.info[brewer.pal.info$category == 'qual',]
col_vector <- unlist(mapply(brewer.pal, qual_col_pals$maxcolors, rownames(qual_col_pals)))
fcolors <- sample(col_vector, length(unique(d2$fruit)), replace = FALSE)

plot_ly(d2, x = ~Date, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', name = ~fruit, fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = list(fcolors)) %>%
  layout(title = 'Sale By Day',
    xaxis = list(title = 'Date'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'Sale'))
```

[image: plot_ly with sales data]